# Value ComboBox Change Value Of TextBox In C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Hello experts i use this code Some time ago and is work ,but now is not work...!! it Says

> (Conversion failed when converting the varchar value
>   'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int)

the code is combobox select value change textbox with Details of this value And thank you in advance.

```
 public partial class test : Form
{

    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Server=AMEER;DataBase=custemer_net;Integrated security=true");
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dttt = new DataTable();
    public test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select *from subscrbtion ", cn);
        da.Fill(dt);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from subscrbtion where id='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'", cn);
        da.Fill(dttt);
        textBox1.Text = dttt.Rows[0]["phone"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What error/exception are your getting here ?

Comment: thank you dear i but the error now sorry for mistake

Comment: when does the error drop? I presume on textBox1.Text = dttt.Rows[0]["phone"].ToString(); Also, please set the combobox datasource after declaring the data and value member

Comment: i do but now error is (Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'aa' to data type int.) the aa is value in database

Comment: At while line of code you get the exception? I think you are sharing us the wrong part of code since exception contains error for conversion to int which is not present anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks guys i tire you i change the event to (comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged) and now error (An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: There is no row at position 0.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a fault in your SqlDataAdapter:

```
new SqlDataAdapter("select * from subscrbtion where id='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", cn);
```

should be

```
new SqlDataAdapter("select * from subscrbtion where id='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'", cn);
```

SelectedValue will point to the Id as you declared under ValueMember.

Extra: set your combobox datasource after declaring its data/value members:

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
```

do change your code according:

```
public test()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Server=AMEER;DataBase=custemer_net;Integrated security=true"))
    {
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select *from subscrbtion ", cn);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
    }
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //for testing
    MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    //

    //clear the datatable dttt
    dttt.Clear();                  //<----------THIS SHOULD BE YOUR NEW SOLUTION

    //refill the datatable with the new information
    using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Server=AMEER;DataBase=custemer_net;Integrated security=true"))
    {
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from subscrbtion where id='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'", cn);
        adapter.Fill(dttt);
    }
    //for testing
    MessageBox.Show(dttt.Rows.Count.ToString());
    //

    //show the data inside the textbox.
    textBox1.Text = dttt.Rows[0]["phone"].ToString();
}
```

Let me know what the messageboxes drop

EDIT:
According to msdn : SqlDataAdapter.Fill() method **ADDS** the values inside the database. ==> this off course means why the test messageboxes always incremented with the rows.

I added the value in the above code, hope this helps

Comment: thank you it work now without error but the value of textbox not change with select and show the first value in textbox but not change

Comment: @ameer; Can you edit you question with the changes you already implemented? This way we can provide further help, it's not clear what you did change and what you didn't.

Comment: i edit My friend This problem made me mad Because I always use this method

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. yes it winforms app is that you mean

Comment: was to fast, please change you current code (Test and event by the edited values i provided, let me know what the messageboxes say everytime you change your value.

Comment: for firt  message  18  then 4 i select second Gives 19 then 5 i select third Gives 20 then 6 . it Three value and number 18,19,20 it id value in database but the other number i dont what

Comment: if you remove the messagebox lines, you will not see anymore lines, the second messagebox was needed for showing how many rows the query returned, this to be sure. Is you id field unique in your table?

Comment: my id i set is primery key and auto identity

Comment: i use for test another combobox it change by the first but the textbox not change

Comment: know i tired you and I am very grateful for your interest

Comment: @ameer, not at all, i guess i found your problem, i'm just looking how to update this into my answer so you have the solution

Comment: You ara Amazing how can i thank you actually expert Thank you dear friend I have started to love Belgium because of you (* _ ^)